# Display a session var without refresh the page

Tags: javascript, php, session

I set a session var in an ajax file like that :`$_SESSION['id_essai']=$ligne[1];`. The value of this var should change at each submit of the form.

Without recharge the page, I want to get the value of this var. So I echo it like that : `echo $_SESSION['id_essai'];` 
My problem is, when I try to echo it, I get the previous value until I recharge the page. I want to refresh this var without recharge the page. How can I do that ?

**EDIT :**

I send a handsontable grid to my ajax file like that :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#submit_button_essai').click(function(){

            $.post("ajax_insert_essai.php",{arr:data_essai}, insert_essai_callback,'json'); 
            return session;
        });
    });
```

In this ajax file, I declare my session var with one value of this grid and I can return it like that :

```
array_unshift($tab_erreur,$_SESSION['id_essai']);

    echo json_encode($tab_erreur);
```

So I send an array of errors AND the session var that I process like that in my callback function:

```
function insert_essai_callback(responseObject,ioArgs) //ajax renvoie les indices des cases erronnées et les messages correspondants.
{
var jsonobject = eval(responseObject);
console.log(jsonobject);
//alert(jsonobject[0]);
var session = jsonobject[0];

for(var item in jsonobject)
{       
        if((item % 2 ) == 0) //Si l'indice est pair, on affiche la couleur
        {
            $("td").eq(jsonobject[item-1]).after("<div class=\"message\">"+jsonobject[item]+"</div>");
        }else //Si l'indice est impair, on affiche le message 
        {
            $("td").eq(jsonobject[item]).css("background-color","red");
        }   

}

}
```

My session var is in `jsonobject[0]`. 
That's my code after trying to return the session var in ajax.

Comment: If you are submitting form using ajax then get the response var which you are setting in session so you can get the value.

Comment: @DishaV. I tried, but it's not so easy. I can't use this method :/

Comment: if you modify something by ajax, you need to refresh it by ajax too. Why its not so easy? Show us some code

Comment: @Daimos Actually, I'm using handsontable (and the user submit the grid), and I send an array to ajax. After, I get an other array which contains the errors of the user. I tried to add my session var into this array and process it in a callback function. But I don't know how to get the var by this way. I will edit my post with more code if you want.

Comment: How do you start your session? Usualy this is done by a cooki or the PHPSESSID parameter in your request.
Make sure you send this in your request.

Comment: can you please post your code that how are you manipulating response?

Comment: I mean `AJAX` response

Comment: @MubinKhalid I edited

Comment: make a backup of file, I'll post code here, update the file and let me know what you see there.

Comment: @Inceddy I start my session with `session_start()` but I don't know `PHPSESSID`, it's maybe the solution, how do you use it, and for what ?

Comment: you're posting the id from grid to ajax page(some `abc` let's say), right? and then posting it back to your page with some id and some error(s), right?

Comment: @MubinKhalid It's right

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that every reuqest will start a new session on the server.

```
<?php

session_start();

// Restart the last session if a session-id is given
if (isset($_GET['session-id'])
    session_id($_GET['session-id']);

/* ... your code here .. */

$response = array('session-id' => session_id());

/* ... add some more values/results to your response */

header('Content-Type: application/json');
die(json_encode($response));

?>
```

Comment: But every request needs to start a new session.

Comment: @Lison Then you wont need a session ;) You want to start the SAME session on every request, not a NEW one. Otherwise the new sessions all start empty!

Comment: Ok, but how can I display it without refresh ? ^^

Answer (score 0):

Set up a new PHP file. Then send the value you need to update to the session variable using ajax on a click event or change event or something. When it receives the value , PHP will update the session value. Then return that variable's value in JSON. Tada You got the updated value. I hope you understood..

example code look like this

in ajax (jquery ajax i am using here)

```
 $.ajax({

  url : 'session.php',
  method : 'POST',
  data : your value to update ,
  dataType : json,
  success : function(data){

      alert(data.value);

   }


 })
```

In session.php file

```
  <?php
    session_start();
    $value = $_POST['value'];
    $_SESSION['value'] = $value;
    $json = array('value' => $_SESSION['value'] );
    print_r(json_encode($json));


  ?>
```

If you need to get value without refresh , call the ajax function on an event. Then update the returned data in to div or something. I hope this one helps ! :)

Comment: It seems to be a good idea but I didn't understand the order. Why should I create a new php file ?

Comment: But I did get the value, I know how to do. It's the "update" part that I don't get.

Comment: Where you want to put the value ??. in the client side or server side ??

Comment: The client side, I want to display it on my page

Comment: $('element').text() pr $('element').html();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83871/discussion-between-jijo-john-and-lison).

Answer (score 0):

create a `process.php` file and `post/get` the `form` there.

```
<form method = 'post' action = 'process.php'>
    <input type = 'hidden' value = 'some_Hidden_Value_that_You_Want' id = 'hidden_id'>
    <!--Some other stuff (Grid may be) -->
    <input type = 'button' value = 'Submit' id = 'submit_form'>
</form>

$("#hidden_id").click(function(){
    var hidden_id = $('#hidden_id').val()
    $.ajax({
        url: 'process.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data:{
            want_this: hidden_id
        },
        success: function(posted){
            alert(posted);
        }
    });
});
```

This will post your stuff to process page.

and on `process.php` or in your case `ajax_insert_essai.php`

do this to view what you're getting

`<?php
    print_r($_POST);
?>`

**EDIT**

**in `callback`**

```
obj = $.parseJSON(jsonobject[0]);
console.log(obj);
// this was to update the page without refreshing the page
//          $this = $('#'+obj.ID).find('td');
//          $this.eq(2).html(obj.username);
//          $this.eq(3).html(obj.password);
//ignore these lines
/*You can access all your stuff then like that*/
condole.log('some id' + obj.id);
//and so on...
```

Comment: or on `ajax_insert_essai.php` do this
`echo json_encode($_POST);`

Comment: I already did: `array_unshift($tab_erreur,$_SESSION['id_essai']);
  echo json_encode($tab_erreur);`

Comment: so, I need to alert in my callback function the session variable ?

Comment: in your `callback` just do `alert(response);`

Comment: you'll get what you want, hopefully :)

Comment: If I alert in my callback, I get the right data in the alert box, but it doesn't update the data in my page.

Comment: post that alert please.

Comment: `alert(jsonobject[0]);` and it contains what I want

Comment: You attach an click-event to a hidden input?!

Answer (score 0):

If the data that will become the new session variable is sent from the page just have it also use the data already on the page to update to page using JavaScript.

If the data you want to get returned is being sent from the page there is no need to re-get the data because it is already on the page.